# a word/phrase for something that is very obvious

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

What do we call it when something is so obvious (about someone) that there is no point in stating it? Is there a phrase or an idiom?

For example:

> It is very obvious that he is a drug addict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to Qwerp-Derp's answer, I found **stand/stick out a mile** which [means](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/stand-stick-out-a-mile):

> to be very obvious or easy to see

I want to talk about something very obvious and recognizable about someone, so I can say:

> His drug addiction **sticks out a mile**.

or

> She **sticks out a mile** with her red hair.

Answer (score 1):

An example of an idiom for "obvious" would be "as clear as day":

> It's **as clear as day** that's he's a drug addict.

You can even use words like "clearly" at the beginning of the sentence to emphasise the phrase you're talking about:

> **Clearly**, he's a drug addict.

It captures the same meaning as "It's very obvious that...", which is what you're looking for, it also adds a layer of emotion to the sentence as well.

Answer (score 1):

One word is [**evident**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/evident):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : clear to the vision or understanding
>
> She spoke with *evident* anguish about the death of her son.
>   The problems have been *evident* for quite some time.

In your case:

> It is **evident** that he is a drug addict.

Or a variation:

> He is **evidently** a drug addict.

---

A longer expression is [**it goes without saying**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/it-goes-without-saying):

> [Cambridge]
>
> used to mean that something is obvious:
>   *Of course, it goes without saying that you'll be paid for the extra hours you work.*

In your case:

> **It goes without saying** that he is a drug addict.

Answer (score 0):

One idiom is “**right in front of your nose**.”

In your example, though, I think this phrase would be more likely to be used to emphasize the point rather than to state it outright. In other words, this wording seems rather clumsy, and I would avoid it:

> It’s right in front of your nose that he’s a drug addict. → not recommended

However, the idiom can still be used effectively, if we add a bit of detail. For example:

> It’s obvious that he’s a drug addict. The signs are right in front of your nose.

TFD defines the idiom as:

> **[in front of (one's) nose](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+front+of+my+nose)**
>   Immediately obvious or clearly apparent.
>   *The solution was right in front of my nose, but I just couldn't grasp it*.